# WinRT GridView disable selection for item, but keep it enabled

Tags: windows, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

This is similar to [disabling selection of a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729315/how-to-disable-selection-a-single-item-in-a-gridview), however, I want to keep the item enabled (for tap, aka click event). Thus simple setting IsEnabled to false is not an option obviously. What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

give the class bound to the item an extra property of type bool (for example canBeSelected), handle the selectionchanged event and check if the bool is false, if it is set selecteditem to null

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using a custom style.

Usage :

```
<GridViewItem Style="{StaticResource NonGridViewItemStyle}"> 
   <!-- Your content here-->
</GridViewItem>
```

Place this Style in a resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="NonGridViewItemStyle"
   TargetType="GridViewItem">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                               Duration="0:0:0.500">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.5" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.500" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                               Duration="0:0:0.500">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.5" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.500" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint" />
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition To="NoSelectionHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                     on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Top" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Right" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Left" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                    <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder"
                            Height="40"
                            Width="40"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Opacity="0"
                            Margin="4">
                        <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill"  Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                        <!-- This extra wrapper grid is necessary because rendertransforms set by the reorder hint animations
                             will be lost when ContentContainer becomes a LTE -->
                        <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       Margin="1" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       StrokeThickness="2"
                                       Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground"
                                       Margin="4"
                                       Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       Opacity="0" />
                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Margin="4">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                    <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                                         In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                                         approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                                               Visibility="Collapsed"
                                               Text="Xg"
                                               Foreground="{x:Null}"
                                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                               AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                                               Visibility="Collapsed"
                                               Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                               Opacity="0"
                                               Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                                       Margin="4"/>
                            <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Margin="4">
                                <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Opacity="0" Height="40" Width="40">
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z"  Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                                       Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                       FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="26.667"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                       Margin="18,9,0,0" 
                                       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The GridViewItem now doesn't show the selectionborder, but it is still selectable...